# Symfony, Doctrine. the functions that i write in my entinty repository are undefined in my controller

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

this is my repository, i wrote the function showActive() in there but when i try to call it on my controller it says that it is not defined.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Pais;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @method Pais|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Pais|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Pais[]    findAll()
 * @method Pais[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class PaisRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Pais::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return pais[]
     */
    public function showActive(){
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $q = $em->createQuery('
            SELECT pa
            FROM App\Entity\Pais pa
            WHERE pa.activo <= 1
        ');
    }
```

heres my controller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Pais;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class ListController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/lista", name="lista")
     */

    public function show(): Response {
        
        $pais = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Pais::class)->showActive();

        return $this->render("main/lista.html.twig",array('paises'=>$pais));

    }
}
```

am i missing something? i didn't find anything in the documentation

i tried to add  use App\Repository\PaisRepository but it didn't fix it.

sorry for the probably dumb question.

Edit: here is my Pais entity.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Pais
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="pais", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="abrev", columns={"abrev"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PaisRepository")
 * 
 */
class Pais
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="descripcion", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $descripcion;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="abrev", type="string", length=10, nullable=false)
     */
    private $abrev;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="activo", type="boolean", nullable=false, options={"default"="1"})
     */
    private $activo = true;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getDescripcion(): ?string
    {
        return $this->descripcion;
    }

    public function setDescripcion(string $descripcion): self
    {
        $this->descripcion = $descripcion;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAbrev(): ?string
    {
        return $this->abrev;
    }

    public function setAbrev(string $abrev): self
    {
        $this->abrev = $abrev;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getActivo(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->activo;
    }

    public function setActivo(bool $activo): self
    {
        $this->activo = $activo;

        return $this;
    }


}
```

Comment: Post your `Pais` entity too.

Comment: It's probably because your Pais entity is not correctly mapped to your repository.

Comment: i already post it. thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: What does a dump of `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Pais::class)` show?

Comment: Drop the double quotes in your repository mapping: @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=App\Repository\PaisRepository)  And maybe do a ceremonial clearing of the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change your repository declaration in your entity as follow:

```
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=App\Repository\PaisRepository::class)
```

Comment: That should yield `App\Repository\PaisRepository`, so the exact same thing that's in there right now. This seems more suitable for a comment.

Comment: @El_Vanja Accident or not this is probably a working answer.  Notice the lack of double quotes.

Comment: @Cerad I always thought these two methods of defining the repository class are equivalents. Where exactly am I mistaken? I can't find anything that would explicitly state why a quoted string literal wouldn't work.

Comment: @El_Vanja this has to do with symfony version. In 3.4 and lower, you declare the repository with quoted string literal, in 4.4 and 5.2 without. See https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/doctrine.html#creating-an-entity-class for 4.4 and https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/repository.html for 3.4

Comment: @FlorentCardot On the other hand, tacking an unnecessary ::class onto the repository makes you answer seem more like a guess.  Consider adding a bit of explanation next time.

Answer (score 0):

In your entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\PaisRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Pais
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="pais", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="abrev", columns={"abrev"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=PaisRepository::class)
 * 
 */
class Pais
```

And try to clear cache after that.